How do I know if I need to use env argument in data.table?
I just read the vignette "Programming on data.table" and the section about environments in advanced R, but I'm having some problems to understand environments and when should I use the env argument in data.table. Suppose the following example
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(id = 1:5, L = letters[1:5])
Y <- data.table(id = 1:3, L = letters[1:3], N = c(10, NA, 12))

ids <- c("id","L")
Y[X, on = (ids)]

if I do it with env
Y[X, on = (ids), env = list(ids = as.list(ids))]

the output is the same, but
substitute2({x}, env = list(x = as.list(ids)))
{
    list(id, L)
}

ids is not a character vector anymore, so why it works? Is there any danger in use the character vector directly without env?

The documentation in help("data.table") doesn't say that on is substituted. And indeed, if you use verbose = TRUE you'll see that it isn't substituted. The documentation also says that on accepts a character vector, which you are passing to it regardless of whether you pass something to env.
